# Installing rpy2 on MacOS

Tags: python, r, pip, rpy2

I've been trying to install RPy2 on MacOS Sierra, for Python 3.6 but the pip installation fails without compiling.

The installation errors out with the message:

```
  clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Any help with the installation would be appreciated.

Comment: This still happens in 2020

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the solution in [this](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340) thread.

`env CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/X.x.x/bin/gcc-X pip install rpy2`

Running the above command by replacing the gcc version with the latest version on your machine should solve the problem. For example, on my mac, I ran

`env CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/gcc-8 pip install rpy2`

Comment: This ended up working for me among numerous supposed solutions. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If using a Miniconda environment this works:

`conda install -c r rpy2`

From: https://anaconda.org/r/rpy2

- macOS Mojave
- Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

If you have the python package `wheel` installed, `pip install` should fetch the pre-compiled binary for OS X, I believe.